# Cannot access a property in mongoose populate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

my message schema:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({  
  conversationId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  seen: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  sender: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'userModel' 
  },
  receiver: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'userModel' 
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true 
});
```

when I console.log the receiver and user, it returns an object, it's there like this:

```
 { _id: 597f7eb1e5131d5a50e18d14,
     updatedAt: 2017-07-31T19:02:09.035Z,
     createdAt: 2017-07-31T19:02:09.035Z,
     fullName: 'ria atayde',
     email: 'myloves@gmail.com',
     password: '$2a$08$Kbkk69.8I9RQvTaRXy3nw.Oj.SEPhKPmhtI/ZWxIHyz2lgYiciVlC',
     todos:
      [ 597f801eab95955c1469bbfc,
        597f8026ab95955c1469bbfd,
        597f8030ab95955c1469bbfe ],
     friendsIds: [ '597f7e3ce5131d5a50e18d13' ],
     active: true,
     __v: 0 }
```

This is my query:

```
await MessageModel.find({ conversationId: { $in: conversationIdsByUser } })
                                      .populate({path:'receiver' ,options: { lean: true}})
                                      .populate({path:'sender' ,options: { lean: true}})
                                      .lean();
```

I already used lean, but still cannot access receiver and sender properties, e.g. receiver._id ? but the object is there?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
await MessageModel.find({ conversationId: { $in: conversationIdsByUser } })
  .populate('receiver sender', { lean: true}})
  .lean();
```

What happens when you try to query without `lean` options?

```
await MessageModel.find({ conversationId: { $in: conversationIdsByUser } })
  .populate('receiver sender');
```

You should try the above as well, since someone on mongoose GitHub commented that using lean with populate is [still buggy](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1382).